# Determine When Flask Server Is Ready For Requests

Tags: python, docker, flask

How can I determine when a flask server is ready to receive traffic?

For example, I have server A, inside a dockerfile, that sends a request to an already running server B, announcing its existence upon the container being run.

However once the already running server (B) recieves that request, it tries to send data to one of server A's routes, receiving the error: `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]`

Is there a flask or external resource that can send a request in the server when it is ready to receive resulting traffic?

Comment: Is the container with server A publishing a port? It should work out of the box, could you provide a command which runs your `A` container?

Comment: Server A is started by Server B with the Docker Python SDK, which runs this: `docker.from_env().containers.run('worker', detach=True, tty=True, volumes =[ ...])` Server B publishes on port 5000, and they are on the same machine, I was hoping to simply connect them by local IPs

Answer (score 0):

I just pull the server state by sending a simple GET request:

```py
    @app.route('/srv_status', methods=['GET'])
    def get_srv_status():
        return 'OK', 200  # just means we're on air
```

If it replied, that means the server is ready to process the requests.
Additionally, it can serve for monitoring purposes.

PS: it's been a while after your question. It would be interesting to learn how you've solved the problem.